# AngularJS : directive with ng-repeat and multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm building an application that has a series of chat windows - each window has it's own controller and the chat windows are setup using ng-repeat:

```
    <div ng-repeat="(id, room) in rooms">
        <div ng-controller="ChatController" ng-init="init(room)" ng-include="'partials/chat-room.html'"></div>
    </div>
```

Now I want to be able to drag and drop the chat windows. I've created a directive:

```
myApp.directive('draggableRoom', function ($document) {
var d = {
    restrict: 'A',
    lastClientX: 0,
    dragging: false,
    elm: null,
    _scope: null,

}
d.link = function (scope, elm, attrs) {

    d._scope = scope;
    d.elm = elm;

    elm.mousedown((function (e) {
        d._scope.startDrag();
        d.dragging = true;
        d.lastClientX = e.clientX;
    }).bind(this));

    $document.mousemove((function (e) {
        if(d.dragging) {

            // Modify the chat's offset
            d._scope.room.offset += d.lastClientX - e.clientX;
            d.lastClientX = e.clientX;

            // Notify the controller
            d._scope.wasDragged();

            // Apply the change
            d._scope.$apply();
        }
    }).bind(this));

    $document.mouseup((function (e) {
        d._scope.stopDrag();
        d.dragging = false;
    }).bind(this));
}
return d;
});
```

The directive is then used in the chat-room partial:

```
<div class="cc-chat-box-outer" ng-style="{'right': room.offset}" draggable-room>
```

This works but the problem is that it only operates on the scope of the last chat room. Is there a way to make it so a new directive is created each time - one for each controller. Or is there an alternative approach.

Comment: Where are you using the directive?

Comment: I just added the code that uses the directive

Comment: Maybe follow the logic for drag/drop from an example in angular's own docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-a-directive-that-adds-event-listeners

Comment: Drag and drop works fine. The problem is that there are 4 rooms and 4 controllers and 4 scopes but only one directive object - this object accesses the scope of that last chat room in the list. i.e. I drag room 1 and room 4 moves. I drag room 2 and room 4 moves etc... I'd like to create a new directive for each item in the ng-repeat so each directive could access the scope of it's room.

Comment: I understand that, but are you 100% sure the directive is only created once? Or is it because the directive you're creating shares things on `d`? Have you put a `console.log` inside the `link` function and saw that it's only called once?

Comment: You were right - I just returned a function like the example rather than adding it to the link property. Now it's working! Thanks for the help!